# Using a caesarian cipher on a string of text in python?

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to slowly knock out all of the intricacies of python.  Basically, I'm looking for some way, in python, to take a string of characters and push them all over by 'x' characters.

For example, inputing abcdefg will give me cdefghi (if x is 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way (for conceptual simplicity):

```
def encode(s):
    l = [ord(i) for i in s]
    return ''.join([chr(i + 2) for i in l])
```

Point being that you convert the letter to ASCII, add 2 to that code, convert it back, and "cast" it into a string (create a new string object).  This also makes no conversions based on "case" (upper vs. lower).

Potential optimizations/research areas:

- Use of StringIO module for large strings
- Apply this to Unicode (not sure how)

Comment: It looks like all you have to do for the Unicode version is to replace `chr()` with `unichr()`.

Answer (score 9):

My first version:

```
>>> key = 2
>>> msg = "abcdefg"
>>> ''.join( map(lambda c: chr(ord('a') +  (ord(c) - ord('a') + key)%26), msg) )
'cdefghi'
>>> msg = "uvwxyz"
>>> ''.join( map(lambda c: chr(ord('a') +  (ord(c) - ord('a') + key)%26), msg) )
'wxyzab'
```

(Of course it works as expected only if msg is lowercase...)

**edit**: I definitely second David Raznick's answer:

```
>>> import string
>>> alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> key = 2
>>> tr = string.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[key:] + alphabet[:key])
>>> "abcdefg".translate(tr)
'cdefghi'
```

Comment: +1 for using lambda, map, and fold (join) all in one line. :)

Comment: What's good about using lambda, map, and join all in one line? Isn't that something one is supposed to try to avoid in Python?

Comment: You can even use alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase, if you don't fancy writing it out.

Comment: @Evan yep, it's not the most pythonic way to do things... list comprehensions are preferred over map and filter and loops with accumulators over reduce (I'm not very happy with that, but it's Guido's Word xD)

Comment: @Evan Agreed. I guess I'm just happy to see others thinking in terms of functional programming.

Comment: If your key is higher than 26 it won't work. But you can circumvent it with `key % 26`

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet is to look at [string.translate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm).  You may have to use make_trans to make the mapping you like.

Answer (score 2):

**This solution works for both lowercase and uppercase:**

```
from string import lowercase, uppercase

def caesar(text, key):
    result = []
    for c in text:
        if c in lowercase:
            idx = lowercase.index(c)
            idx = (idx + key) % 26
            result.append(lowercase[idx])
        elif c in uppercase:
            idx = uppercase.index(c)
            idx = (idx + key) % 26
            result.append(uppercase[idx])
        else:
            result.append(c)
    return "".join(result)
```

**Here is a test:**

```
>>> caesar("abcdefg", 2)
'cdefghi'
>>> caesar("z", 1)
'a'
```

Comment: To fix what I mentioned in my previous comment, you need to use parenthesis because `%` has a higher precedence than `+`: `idx = (idx + key) % 26`

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out, heh. I forgot that modulus is higher.

Answer (score 1):

Another version. Allows for definition of your own alphabet, and doesn't translate any other characters (such as punctuation). The ugly part here is the loop, which might cause performance problems. I'm not sure about python but appending strings like this is a big no in other languages like Java and C#.

```
def rotate(data, n):
    alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz")

    n = n % len(alphabet)
    target = alphabet[n:] + alphabet[:n]

    translation = dict(zip(alphabet, target))
    result = ""
    for c in data:
        if translation.has_key(c):
            result += translation[c]
        else:
            result += c

    return result

print rotate("foobar", 1)    
print rotate("foobar", 2)    
print rotate("foobar", -1)
print rotate("foobar", -2)
```

Result:

```
gppcbs
hqqdct
emmazq
dllzyp
```

The make_trans() solution suggested by others is the way to go here.